# undefined value giving at mongo db collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a mongo db collection and retrieve the data from the response but it is giving me undefined or [object]. How do I fix it?

The dependencies

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var User = require("./model/user");
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
 User.find({ username: "test3" }).exec(function(err, User) {
            console.log(User);
            console.log(User.image);
```

but the console log is giving undefined value

Log when the entry is created then User and then User.image:

```
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636858+00:00 app[web.1]: _id: 5eef7c9eb9d3770017b5d46c,
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636859+00:00 app[web.1]: username: 'test3',
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636862+00:00 app[web.1]: course: [ { _id: 5eef7c9eb9d3770017b5d46d, name: 'iwp', credits: 4 } ],
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636862+00:00 app[web.1]: image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dtarijclg/image/upload/v1592574822/unknown_lfjhkc.png',
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636863+00:00 app[web.1]: __v: 0
2020-06-21T15:28:30.636863+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243900+00:00 app[web.1]: [
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243910+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243911+00:00 app[web.1]: _id: 5eef7c9eb9d3770017b5d46c,
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243912+00:00 app[web.1]: username: 'test3',
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243913+00:00 app[web.1]: course: [ [Object] ],
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243914+00:00 app[web.1]: image: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/dtarijclg/image/upload/v1592574822/unknown_lfjhkc.png',
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243914+00:00 app[web.1]: __v: 0
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243915+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-06-21T15:28:47.243915+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-06-21T15:28:47.244172+00:00 app[web.1]: undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

`User.find({ username: 'test3'}, function (err, docs) { console.log(docs)});`
Try this code and avoid using the same model name in exec function because User is model and you are using that same method in callback.

Comment: i don't know why but it is working for docs[0].category